# Storing char pointers then fill it later on

Tags: c++, pointers, char, void, strcpy

I'm having a small issue here, so I'm storing a char pointer ( rather an array ), in a void pointer as following:

```
char result[255];
CEVariable result_var(CEType::string, result);
```

Now the result_var is then passed on to my engine, stored as a pointer, the variable structure is then accessed later on: ( m_pData is a void*, pointing to the char array )

```
strcpy((char*)pVar->m_pData, "42");
```

But no data is written to it, and I'm sure it points to the result array, as I checked the addresses. Maybe I have gotten something wrong in my understanding of void pointers, but the following seems to work: ( Just testing )

```
    char dest[255];
    void*ptr = dest;
    strcpy((char*)ptr, "asdsa");
    std::cout << dest;
```

The result array turns into an unreadable format, most likely random memory. Maybe never written to. My question is what may the issue be?

EDIT: CEVariable::

```
class CEVariable
{
public:
    CEVariable() {}
    CEVariable(CEType t, void* mem)
    {
        m_Type = t;
        m_pData = mem;
    }

    // Variable Type
    CEType m_Type;

    // Variable Data Ptr
    void* m_pData;
};
```

The result does not go out of scope as all is executed in one function.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How does `CEVariable` look? What does the constructor do? Your `char result[255]` looks like a local variable so it will go out of scope at the end of the block.

Comment: How does `strcpy((char*)pVar->m_pData, "42");` relate to the initial definition?

Comment: Also, how do you pass `result_var` to where you store it? You follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)? You do deep copying when needed?

Comment: The best answer to *all* these questions (mine and others) is to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: see edited post, I adressed it, and all is done in the main function, so nothing should go out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CEVariable::m_pData` is only a *pointer*. It has no space reserved for the string.

You should first allocate some memory for the string (e.g. using `new[]`), and then `strcpy()` the source string to that reserved space:

```
// Dynamically allocate some memory with new[].
// For the string "42", it's 3 chars: '4', '2' and terminating NUL '\0'.
// For a generic string, you may want to use strlen(s)+1.
pVar->m_pData = new char[3];

// Copy string
strcpy(static_cast<char*>(pVar->m_pData), "42");

// Don't forget to release the string memory with delete[]
// when it's no longer needed.
// (e.g. in CEVariable's destructor.)
```

Note that in C++ you should use C++-style casts instead of C-style casts.

The problem with your *stack-allocated* buffer `char result[255]` is that it will be destroyed when the variable goes out of scope. Instead, if you allocate the string memory with `new[]` (from the *heap*), this memory will still be available after the scoped-ending brace `}`. The memory will be released when you call `delete[]` on the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

If the scope that had `char result[255]` is no longer "alive", this is undefined behavior. You need to use `new` to allocate heap memory, or make it `static`.

Comment: The array should still be "alive" as all is executed in one function.

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code:

```
char result[255];
CEVariable result_var(CEType::string, result);
```

If variable `result` is a local variable in some function, then you need to make sure that you do not use variable `result_var` once you're outside **the scope** of this function.